Can can I make <button> tag editable within CKEditor?
I am using CKEditor 5, version 40.2.0 within the context of Drupal 10 (not sure if the latter is relevant though). Via Source I add the following HTML snippet
<div>
    <button>Button text</button>
</div>

When switching to normal edit view, the  element is visually "marked" as an HTML object and it's not editable; I cannot place the cursor within the button text and therefore change it:

And by inspecting the HTML I see the markup is modified as follows:
<div>
    <span class="html-object-embed ck-widget" data-html-object-embed-label="HTML object" contenteditable="false">
        <button class="html-object-embed__content">Button text</button>
    </span>
⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠</div>


I found this relevant issue (with no responses yet), but I am not sure if this is a bug or feature request. And most important, is there a workaround/configuration or something I can do/use to prevent this from happening?
